# Apostrophe CMS Rich Text Global Toolbar

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a global default toolbar and global default styles that will be displayed by every rich-text-widget in the site, unless overridden on a per-widget basis.

e.g. I'd like to use something like:

```
{{ apos.area(data.widget, 'content', {
  widgets: {
    'apostrophe-rich-text': {}
  }
}) }}
```

and still have it display the toolbar with the Styles dropdown and some pre-defined styling options.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the Apostrophe team will write a wrapper macro for areas/singletons with the default configuration baked in.

A simple example would be like:

In `views/area.html`

```
{% macro defaultArea(context, name) %}
  {{ apos.area(context, name, {
    'apostrophe-rich-text': {},
    'apostrophe-images': {}
  }) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then in your template

```
{% import 'apostrophe-templates:areas.html' as areas %}

<div>
  {{ areas.defaultArea(data.page, 'body') }}
</div>
```